# using type = smth. and templated types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using

I have some trouble with a piece of C++ code.

First, if I do this, it works quite well :

```
struct A
{
    using my_type1 = double;
    using my_type2 = int;
};

struct B
{
    using size_type = A::my_type2;
};
```

However, I want to be able to choose my_type1, so I went the template way :

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    using my_type1 = T;
    using my_type2 = int;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    using size_type = A<T>::my_type2;
};
```

Here, gcc fails with : "expected type specifier" on the line

```
using size_type = A<T>::my_type2;
```

I could just put my_type2 in template too but this is a type that shouldn't change much.

So why doesn't my method work ? Thanks!

Comment: Templates won't let you choose types at runtime anyway.

Comment: @n.m. : yes, that's not what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `typename`:

```
using size_type = typename A<T>::my_type2;
```

Comment: Okay, works perfectly! Where did you get to know this ?